# how to rollback an entity from two entities to persists in jpa

Tags: java, jpa

I want to rollback an entity from two entities to persists in a method where if one get exception then other will be rollback. Like as..

```
  @Autowired
  XYZDao xyzDao;

  private XYZ beanXYZ;

  @Autowired
  ABCDao abcDao;

  private ABC beanABC;

  public void saveBoth(){
    try {
        xyzDao.persist(beanXYZ);
        abcDao.persist(beanABC);

        } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("This is error : " + e);
        logger.fatal("This is fatal : " + e);
        }
    }
```

How can I rollback both entities if one is not persist.
Please Suggest me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can annotate your `saveBoth()` method with `@Transactional` annotation.

```
@Transactional
public void saveBoth(){
try {
    xyzDao.persist(beanXYZ);
    abcDao.persist(beanABC);

    } catch (Exception e) {
    logger.error("This is error : " + e);
    logger.fatal("This is fatal : " + e);
    }
}
```

Do also look at [this](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring/4.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html) link for a better understanding of how transaction can be configured and how it works.

Comment: Thanks @Abdullah Wasi for good solution. '@Transactional' annotation works well. Thanks..

Comment: Please also upvote my answer if it helped you. Thanks brother.

Answer (score 0):

The behavior you want is provided by Transaction mechanism. You can achieve this by creating new DAO for combined operation which contains operations to save both beans in one transaction. Something like below:

```
persistAbcAndXyz(BeanABC beanABC, BeanXYZ beanXYZ){
    try{
        //get transaction from EMF and begin
        //emf.getTransaction().begin()

        //save beanABC
        //save beanXYZ

        //emf.getTransaction().commit()
    }
    catch( PersistenceException ex){
       //rollback transaction
       //emf.getTransaction().rollback();
    }
}
```

In case your DAOs refer to different databases such that they could not share same `EntityManager` `Transaction`, you can use external transaction management library like Spring Transactions.